# Reading PLY file with color

Tags: vtk, solidworks

I have a PLY file (exported from Solidworks inc. vertex colors), which I want to visualize using vtk.
The header information of the file shows that it contains some color information:

```
ply
format binary_little_endian 1.0
comment SOLIDWORKS generated,length unit = Millimeter
element vertex 8927
property float x
property float y
property float z
element face 17436
property uchar red
property uchar green
property uchar blue
property uchar alpha
property list uchar int vertex_indices
end_header
```

I read the file using `vtkPLYReader`, but somehow I do not see different colors on the model. The whole model is represented as white. If I open the file in MeshLab the colors are there.

```
 dataPath = 'model.PLY'

 reader = vtk.vtkPLYReader()
 reader.SetFileName(dataPath)

 polyDataMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
 polyDataMapper.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
 polyDataMapper.ScalarVisibilityOff()
 polyDataMapper.Update()

 actor = vtk.vtkActor()
 actor.SetMapper(polyDataMapper)
 actor.GetProperty().SetOpacity(1.0)
 actor.Modified()

 renderer.AddActor(actor)
```

Any suggestion, how could I visualize it with colors?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line
polyDataMapper.ScalarVisibilityOff()

or rather explicitly write
polyDataMapper.ScalarVisibilityOn()